# Failed to start Freeswitch in centos?

Tags: linux, centos, freeswitch

I have just installed Freeswitch in Centos7 . when i check my Freeswitch status , its failing to start with following error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have attached copy of both command and the logs file showing errors as well

> Starting freeswitch

```
 [root@localhost log]# systemctl start freeswitch
 [root@localhost log]# systemctl status freeswitch
```

> ```
>     ●Started FreeSWITCH.
> ```

```
 Feb 17 22:56:38 localhost freeswitch: ERROR: Failed to set SCHED_FIFO scheduler (Operation not permitted)
    Feb 17 22:56:38 localhost freeswitch: ERROR: Could not set nice level
    Feb 17 22:56:38 localhost freeswitch: Cannot open pid file /opt/freeswitch/run/freeswitch.pid.
    Feb 17 22:56:38 localhost systemd: freeswitch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
    Feb 17 22:56:38 localhost systemd: Unit freeswitch.service entered failed state.
    Feb 17 22:56:38 localhost systemd: freeswitch.service failed.
```

Comment: Check this: `/usr/bin/freeswitch: No such file or directory`

Comment: You're missing the freeswitch binary as @RomeoNinov already said and as the log shows...

Comment: can you please have a look again at my log errors again

Answer (score 1):

Need to check logs for errors at /var/log/freeswitch/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of a permission problem. Try this:

```
$ chmod 777 freeswitch
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ps aux | grep freeswitch
```

Check whether a freeswitch is already running so it can't open the pid file:

```
/opt/freeswitch/run/freeswitch.pid
```

If there is a freeswitch already running, kill it:

```
kill 9 {pid}
```